# Exclude selectors from a parent div

Tags: jquery, click

I need to trigger an event (e.g. hide a floating shopping cart) when clicking on the background of the page (#page) but this event not to occur when clicking inside content. So I need this event to occur on the space: page minus content. How do I achieve it? Thanks

If I have this structure:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
   <div id="content">
     here
   </div>
</div>
</body>

var outer= jQuery("#page");
jQuery(outer).click(function(){
  jQuery(cos_de_cumparare).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check the target of the event and act accordingly

```
var outer= jQuery("#page");
outer.click(function(e){
       //trigger the event only if the target of the click is the page
       if(e.target.id === 'page'){
         alert('click');
       }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wNsd7/

Comment: I tested and this seems the most elegant solution. I thank you all of you for help. Regards

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can stop the event propagating up the chain.

The usual way to do this is to attach a click event to the child elements and stop propagation from there such that:

```
$("#page div").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/wMffX/)

Comment: No, i don't think that this has anything to do with what he is trying to do

Comment: Ah ok you intended that in addiction to the other!i didn't get it at first!Yes this definitely works but can cause problem with event delegation.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this and check http://jsfiddle.net/qgUjb/4/

```
$("#page").click(function(event) {
   if(event.target.id == "content") return;
   $("#content").toggle();
});
```